# How to change width of div to 100% with jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs side by side and when one isn't there, I want the other to have a width of 100%.

```
while ($array = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
     if (!empty($array['photoname'])){
          echo '<div class="photo"></div>';
     }
        echo  '<div class="info"></div>';
}
```

Here's my Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //check if photo div exists
    if ($('.photo').length){

    }else{
        $('.info').css('width', '100%');
    }
});
```

So if there is no photo div I want the info div to get a width of 100%. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

If I don't have any photo divs showing, the above works and sets info divs to 100%. But when I have a photo div anywhere on the page, then none of the info divs are set to 100% even if they dont have a photo div next to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="photo">a</div> <div class="info">a</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //check if photo div exists
    $( ".main" ).each(function( index ) {
       var thisPhoto = $(this).find('.photo').html();
        if(thisPhoto==undefined){
            
            $(this).find('.info').css('width', '100%');
        }    
     });
    
        
});
```

CSS

```
.main{
        display:block;
        color:red;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
    .photo{
        float:left;
         width:50%;
        display:block;
        background:red;
        height:100%;
    }
    .info{
        float:left;
         width:50%;
        display:block;
        background:red;
        height:100%;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/Hk2Zx/)

**EDIT: Please see my updated jsfiddle, the reason why your jQuery is not working as expected is because you refer to class in a global score, as you want to modify your divs in a row basis you will have to somehow iterate trough each of them, this is when Jquery comes to the play again, in the updated code I'm using the find() function on each iteration, this will affect only the current row as the scope is reduced to the iterated element only.**

Comment: It doesn't work, check my answer, `$('.photo').length` will always return `1` and will be true.

Comment: `if ($('.photo').html().length){` isn't working for me. I removed the photo div and put `alert('hi');` under `else` but it didn't alert me.

Comment: check the updated demo, i changed it a bit and when you run it without the div it will alert

Comment: the `$('.photo').hide();` isn't necessary, check my PHP again. And I removed the .html() and it alerted me this time. But please check my update above, maybe it will help? I think the jquery isnt checking all the divs because it is a while loop so there are multiple divs with these classes.

Comment: The index is only a variable that holds the number of iteration, for example for the first element it values 0, for the second 1 and so on.. it this particular example we are not using it you could remove it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it might be just as easy to handle it server-side.  In your logic, simply change the CSS class you assign based on whether you have one or two DIVs.

```
<? if (hasPhotos) { ?>
    <div class="photo two-column left-column">...</photo>
    <div class="info two-column last-column">...</info>
<? } else { ?>
    <div class="info">...</info>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem here:

```
$('.update_info').css('width', '100%');
```

Your info div is not class update_info, it's class info, so change to:

```
$('.info').css('width', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `length` returns a number, so you have to check for it to be zero.
Your if statement would look like this then:

`if ($('.photo').length == 0){ ...`

Comment: You don't have to explicitly check for if(x==0) if x is numeric because if() will evaluate to true for any non-zero number